# How can I extract telegram group members with non-ASCII characters names?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am using Telethon to extract participants of a certain group.

I noticed that I cannot extract members with Arabic names. When I (manually) add these members to my contact list and give them English (characters) names, I can extract them from the group using client.get_participants().

I do not want to go through the process of adding them. Is there any other solution to extract these specific members?

Comment: Are you looking for a function to transcribe the name?

Comment: Telethon doesn't care about what the names look like. Your terminal however might. If you're printing the names, printing is probably what's failing with a specific error. You could try printing a name manually to check if this is the issue and then work from there.